# Rails, production environment exception page shows in development environment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm running Rails 4.2.0.beta and am having a weird issue; instead of the usual Rail’s page displaying exceptions in development mode, like so:
[image]

I get the following:
[image]
This page appears with any exception.

I have double checked that I'm under development mode and that 'consider_all_requests_local' is set to true in config/environments/development.rb.

I noticed I'm receiving the following error when I hit an exception

```
" ERROR Rack::Lint::LintError: Response body was given for HEAD request, but should be empty
    /Users/Rali/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0-dev/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0.beta/lib/rack/lint.rb:20:in `assert'"
```

I assume it's somehow related.. Any ideas?

Comment: Just throwing a few things out there: 1. How are you checking you're in development mode? 2. Are you precompiling assets/serving static assets? 3. Is there a particular reason you're using a beta version?

Comment: isnt that a default error page that heroku will throw regardless of the error type? you have to check the logs like it says to find the cause

Comment: @AbrahamChan 1) I'm checking the environment via Rails.env in console. Also, I get '=> Rails 4.2.0.beta1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000' when I start the server. 2) No 3) No, there's no particular reason - I guess I shouldn't, huh? :(

Comment: @Richlewis yes, it resembles the Heroku 404 page but I'm running a local server in development mode.

Comment: Well, for what is worth I just created a brand new app, using 4.2.0.beta1, and the routing exceptions show up fine.

Comment: Thanks for checking! Not sure what I did wrong. I just downgraded to 4.1 and all is well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for digging out a month-old question but if there is anyone with same issue (like me), though with version `4.2.0.rc1` I fixed it by removing `gem 'web-console'` from `Gemfile` which is by default added when generating new application.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `gem 'web-console'` also solved this issue for me in Rails 5.1, for anyone stumbling into this issue 4 years later...